# Why is "number" undeclared when I declared it in the function?

Tags: c, scope, identifier, undeclared-identifier

```
#include <stdio.h>

void numberisone()
{
    int number = 1;
}

int main()
{
    numberisone();
    
    printf("%d", number);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm fairly new to programming so make the explanation as simple as possible :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: The variable `number` is defined in the function: its scope is limited to the function.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.in/c-tutorial/variable-scope/

Comment: Because identifiers only exist inside the scope they were declared. This is incredibly fundamental stuff, so instead of treating SO as an interactive beginner tutorial, you should probably just take a non-interactive one.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the declaration of the variable `number` is the outermost block of the function `numberisone`

```
void numberisone()
{
    int number = 1;
}
```

Outside the function the variable is not alive and visible.

So the used identifier `number` in main is undeclared

```
printf("%d", number);
```

To make your program more or less meaningful declare the function like

```
int numberisone( void )
{
    return 1;
}
```

and in main write

```
int number = numberisone();
```

Comment: Re “alive and visible”: This conflates visibility and lifetime. And it is needless; for this question, simply say “Outside the function, the variable is not visible” and leave lifetime out of it. Outside the function, the identifier is not visible. Outside the function, the object is alive as long as execution of the function has not ended.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numberisone()
{
    int number = 1;
    return number;
}

int main()
{
    int num_1 = 0;
    num_1 = numberisone();

    printf("%d", num_1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should really add an explanation to this as just supplying code does not assist the reader to learn from your answer. Please use the [edit] to improve this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Variables declare inside a function have a scope inside that function only that is the variable can be use only inside the function. If you nee you can return the value from the function as like,

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    
    int numberisone()
    {
        int number = 1;
        return number;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        printf("%d", numberisone());
        return 0;
    }
```